# Zend Framework and Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework

I've used jquery many times but I'm currently learning Zend Framework. I think im understanding it better.

I'm trying to do something as simple as putting the tabs from jquery-ui but its not working.

This is my layout file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://localhost/site/site/public/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/site/site/public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the view where I'm trying to display it:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>



<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the source code of the site that it displays:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>



<meta charset="utf-8">



<script src="http://localhost/site/site/public/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/site/site/public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>



<script>

    $(function() {

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    });

    </script>







<div id="tabs">

    <ul>

        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>

        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>

        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">

        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>

    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">

        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>

    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">

        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>

        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>

    </div>

</div>







</body>

</html>
```

I really don't see anything wrong. I tested the files to see if I was calling from the right folder and they work.

I know Zend has a ZendX library but I really don't see an advantage for it so I'm trying to do it manually. Is it that to use jquery i have to use that library? Or what is wrong with this?! Thanks!

**--EDIT
I guess I had to put the theme. Now is working. The accordion was working without it but I guess tabs need it. Thanks!**

Comment: check on the console if jquery and jquery ui are loaded or not , and add the jquery ui css file to for the test.
ZendX_JQuery has more to do with form fields. you can add a date picker in php rather than in plain javascript.
Zend is more powerfull with Dojo integration though , you can do crazy things and it is worth to check out if you are doing a full HTML5 app.

Comment: Hi. I've heard to check the console many times. I'm using chrome. I think its ctrl+shift+i . I try that, in the console part it shows nothing, how would I know if it's loading jquery and the ui?

Comment: type 'http://localhost/site/site/public/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' in ur browser url - does it load the jqsource?

Comment: It worked... Once i put the css now it works. I was doing it without a theme, the accordion and the other ones were working but not the tabs. I feel kinda stupid now. I'll just use the theme and modify it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I had to put the theme. Now is working. The accordion was working without it but I guess tabs need it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that it works as written. After all, you are invoking  `$('#tabs').tabs()` **before** the `#tabs` element is actually placed into the DOM. Typically, one would address that by wrapping the plugin invocation with a `$(document).ready()` call.